# Regular expression - Kleene star of a union expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to code something that returns randomly a possible result after going through a regular expression.

I was sort of confused on how to tackle this when you have kleene star of a union expression.

If you have (a + b)* then does this mean that you indefinitely choose between a or b and repeat it a definite number of times, or do you just randomly choose between a or b twice.

If it is the former, then would it logically make sense to first generate a random number to determine how many times I'm going to randomly choose between a or b, and then for each time I randomly choose the element I generate another random number that then repeats the element that many times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking what kind of things match `(a | b)*`, you might as well think of it in terms of a grammar:

```
<expression> := <empty> | <parens><expression>
<parens>     := a | b
```

That's what a `*` operator really means: for any expression `x`, `x*` matches either the empty string or `(x)(x*)` (this is a recursive definition).

If you want to randomly generate a string that matches the expression, then that's a much more complicated matter. You now have to think in terms of which distribution you want to use, because the length of the string is unbounded, and it's impossible to have a uniform distribution over an unbounded range. (In other words, you can't pick a random length between 0 and infinity uniformly, so you'd have to decide how you're going to pick that in the first place.) Once you have your length problem resolved, expand `(a | b)*` into `(a | b)` repeated N times (where N is your randomly-chosen length) and resolve each parenthesized subexpression separately — for instance, if you choose to expand the subexpression 3 times, that would become `(a | b)(a | b)(a | b)`, which will match all of `aaa`, `baa`, `aba`, `bba`, `aab`, `bab`, `abb` and `bbb`.

Comment: So if I decided to have the max repeat for * be 10, then (a|b)* would be equivalent to randomly choosing (a|b) ten times and the longest length for the result would be 10?

Comment: Technically, if the _maximum_ length is 10, you have all 2,047 possible results that can arise from all lengths from 0 to 10: the empty string, `a`, `b`, `aa`, `ab`, `ba`, `bb`, `aaa`, and so on. You can choose amongst them uniformly (since there's a finite number of them) or you can weight them by length, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if the string is a member of a Kleene star applied
set, such as:

```
{"a", "b"}* = {ε, "a", "b", "aa", "ab", "ba", "bb", "aaa", "aab", ...}
```

then the regex `^[ab]*$` will work including an empty string.
If you want to limit the length of the string, say `10`, then try `^[ab]{,10}$`.